# Using wsgi with python 2.6 on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, python, mod-wsgi

I'm using libapache2-mod-wsgi 2.5-1 on ubuntu. Python 2.4 and 2.6 also installed. On server start i get the following warns in the error log:

```
[Sun Nov 29 14:23:47 2009] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.6.2.
[Sun Nov 29 14:23:47 2009] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.6.4.
```

In order to resolve this problem, I might recompile wsgi for 2.6.4. The related [launchpad ticket's](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mod-wsgi/+bug/339352) status is 'fix released'. Despite i get the warns. How could I fix this problem?

Comment: It's not clear whether there is a real problem at all. You answered yourself how you could make warnings go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a system where the Python installation provides a shared library and mod_wsgi is using that shared library, as opposed to the library being linked statically, then it is not an issue.

This issue is described in:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Python_Version_Mismatch

Suggest you read that whole document.